# CORS Error in Ionic + Laravel App developement

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, ionic3

I had made a website in laravel.Now Iam making its mobile App using Ionic 3.

I am facing an following issue while making a API call to backend of laravel.

`localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xyz.dev/request/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

Let say there are 12  routes defined in web.php of laravel.

Then in my project out of 12, 6 routes are for desktop web application and remaining 6 routes are prefixed with `/mobile` so that I can consume it in MY API.
I am facing that issue while making any request through mobile app which is in IONIC and backend is in Larave.

Please Help me for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your laravel project through which you call apis

Put this in your filters.php file

```
Route::filter('alloworigin', function()
{   
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
});
```

Through this you can successfully call cross platform api..

or 
you can also put this in your ajax call

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/symbol/junk', 
            headers:{
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With',
                'X-Random-Shit':'123123123'
            }})
```